# Where should I troubleshoot when a mongoose query delivers a different list than mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongoose

windows box. most db operations are working ok. The DB is populated through a script following the pattern I read on the mongoose quick start guide. And I use same pattern to query. The trouble is: I am getting the wrong data back (some very old contained in a dropped db) and by that I mean:

one week ago

**A.** ran populate.js (via mongoose) over data with timestamps Jan - Mar
   the documents use scheme where the json object has a seq field (1 to whatever) & timestamp
   and inserted via a save using the pattern on mongoose quick start site

```
       var data = new model(dataPoint);
       data.save(function(err,d){ 
           if (err) console.log("..."); 
       });
```

**B.** Deleted the files containing January timestamps

**C.** using mongo shell, removed the collection, dropped the database

today

1. ran populate.js (via mongoose) to load data Feb & Mar
2. via mongo shell, a query shows the data loaded as expected. verified (each document has a sequence ID 1-140 and a timestamp (ISODATE)
3. run query from mongoose and the data from one week ago appears.

In mongo shell:

```
    >use testa
    >db.A.find({seq:1}).pretty(){
        "seq" : 1,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5333993967a589342e728bb3"),
        "stats" : {
            "start" : ISODate("2014-02-24T06:33:20.034Z"),
            "duration" : 134
            },
        "__v" : 0
      }
```

In contrast, a Mongoose query in a nodejs script yields unexpected results:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
model.find(function(err,msg){
    mongoMsg = msg;
    console.log(msg[0].stats.start);   // bad data
});
```

Comment: Sorry about the question format. First one.

Comment: One possible cause. Between the first DB instance and the second, the schema changed. Another reason I was so perplexed since the query gets results for a different schema also the second is schema is an object nested in the first.

Comment: Ah, the culprit var modnew = new model(OLD_MODEL_NAME, NEW_SCHEMA)